# lubridate - get hours and minutes from decimal hours

Tags: r, datetime, time, lubridate

I have decimal hours in format `245.85` equalling to `245:51:00` in `[hh]:mm:ss` format.

I want to transform the decimal hours to hh:mm format, but how do I do it?

the original calculation that renders 245.85 is:

```
library(lubridate)
time_length(hm("7 27")*33,unit = "hours")
```

what I want is `245:51` or `245:51:00`
If I use as.period I get days too - like in:

```
as.period(dhours(time_length(hm("7 27")*33,"hours")))
[1] "10d 5H 51M 0S"
```

and for background - my aim is to multiply hours and minutes (e.g. 7:27) by an arbitrary integer (e.g. 33) and get result back in hh:mm format - avoiding days (as in `as.period` example above). Say if a piece of work takes 7 hours and 27 minutes and we give me 33 pieces of such work to do per year, it should take me about this many work hours (and minutes) to do.

Comment: can't you just insert a custom function that converts from decimal hours to hours + minutes yourself? What motivates using this library for it?

Comment: `paste0((245.85 %/% 1),":", round((245.85 %% 1)* 60),":00")`

Comment: Do you want your output to be a time format? If you're just interested in the syntax, yo could do:
x<- as.period(dhours(time_length(hm("7 27")*33,"hours")), )
paste(x@day*24 + x@hour, x@minute, sep = ":")

Comment: sorry, I am not very experienced in programming and someone told me - people probably have solved these problems before

Comment: Thanks very much, these are very helpful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really only the H:M:S format that gives you trouble, try

```
library(hms)
hms(hours=245.85)
```

which yields `245:51:00`